# Is it ok to name a string var ends with suffix map?

Tags: go, coding-style, conventions

If I want to get a map from a json string stored in a var, is it ok if this var name ends with suffix `Map`?
for example:

```golang
CrashBmMap string
crashMap := map[string][]string
...
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(CrashBmMap), &crashMap)
```

Comment: "crashMap" is a valid identifier. What exactly are you concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to name a string var ends with suffix map?

It will compile and work as intended, so it is OK.

Should you do it? This is somewhat opinion based. There is no Go convention for this, but there's a good blog post by Dave Cheney: [You shouldn’t name your variables after their types for the same reason you wouldn’t name your pets “dog” or “cat”](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/names):

> The name of a variable should describe its contents, not the *type* of the contents. Consider this example:
>
> ```
> var usersMap map[string]*User
> ```
>
> What are some good properties of this declaration? We can see that it’s a map, and it has something to do with the `*User` type, so that’s probably good. But `usersMap` *is* a map and Go, being a statically typed language, won’t let us accidentally use a map where a different type is required, so the `Map` suffix as a safety precaution is redundant.
>
> ... My suggestion is avoid any suffix that resembles the type of the variable. Said another way, if `users` isn’t descriptive enough, then `usersMap` won’t be either.